# Using remote plugin to load images in Desire2Learn

Tags: desire2learn

I want to insert a link in the image upload page in the D2L LMS which allows the user to upload an image from our Gravatar service. I understand I can do it through the valence content API but just as we can put in links in the insert stuff sidebar, can we also wrap an LTI link into a link on the image upload page?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is sample code for creating a remote plugin that allows you to insert images using the Insert Stuff Framework, which was introduced in the following blog post: http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2013/11/11/making-development-easier-with-the-remote-plugins-test-service/. This sample uses LTI and the Valence Learning Framework APIs to insert images.

Comment: Thanks Sarah! Dont know if you remember us, this is the handle for the developers group at Ohio State Univ.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to see you guys on Stack. Hopefully you'll join us on the ValenceUsers forum, too! https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/valenceusers

Answer (score 1):

The [Remote Plugin Service](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/ui-ext/rplugins.html) builds on LTI to let you integrate with D2L's LMS in more "native user interaction" kinds of ways. The "Insert Stuff" framework is one of these, as you've recognized. While D2L does intend to offer more Remote Plugin configuration types in the future, currently there is no configuration type for integration with the image upload interaction point. This is, however, a good idea; I'd encourage you to suggest it on the [Product Ideas Exchange](https://community.desire2learn.com/d2l/lp/navbars/1796/customlinks/external/15394) in the D2L Community site, or make a request for this enhancement through your account or partner manager at D2L.